When I call the data from a fetch call, one section will throw an error, but still log in the console correctly, while every other section works fine
I'm using the DND5E API and React. I call the data and save it to a variable called primaryChoices, which is an array starting at proficiency_choices in the API under the classes section (https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/monk).
I iterate over that with .map and from that I use element.from.options, also an array, and iterate over that with a nested .map and extract the value of options.item.index.
That logic works for every class except monk. It's set up the same as every other class in the API and even logs correctly outside the .map functions with this:
console.log(primaryChoices[0].from.options[0].item.index)

That same console log logs the other classes too, and I can even display any information from them with no errors.
// after the data is called from the api it gets saved to character.class.primary
const primaryChoices = character?.class?.primary?.proficiency_choices


            if(!isPrimaryEmpty && isSecondaryEmpty){

                return (primaryChoices.map((element) => (
                    <div>
                    <strong>Choose {`${element.choose}`} for {`${primary.name}`}</strong>
                       
                        {element.from.options.map((option) => {

                            return(
                                <p>
                              // this log works properly
                                   {console.log(option.item.name)}
                                   
                             //this input throws the error in the name attribute
                                    <input onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e, element, option)} type='checkbox' name={option.item.index} />
                                    <label htmlFor={option.item.index}>{option.item.name}</label>
                                </p>
                            )
                        })}

                    </div>
                )))

            }else if(...){...}

The element.choose and primary.name both work fine with any class.
I checked the path and it logs correctly without throwing errors and I went to the API page and double checked the path.

What exactly happens with the monk class?

it logs correctly on the console and throws an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index') or Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') when option.item.index or option.item.name is called. option.item is an object

Where in your code are you logging it? Relative to the successful log, where does the error occur?

i can call the log in the p tag and get the data. the very next line(the input) throws the error. i just added logs to the snippet
